# How value of id goes from action method to the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-post, http-get

I have a method `AddAddress(int Id)` and I cannot work out how the value of Id goes to the View (when I check `view source` of the rendered view the value is there).

I have to create more complicated but similar method and i just don't get how the value of `Id` goes to the rendered View. I just need to know how it happens. Many thanks

AddAddress Method :

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddAddress (int Id)
{      
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddAddress(AddressModel address)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View("AddAddress", address);
    }
    if (!address.Address_Id.HasValue|| address.Address_Id == 0)
    {
        _addressService.insertAddress(address);
    }
    else
    {
        _addressService.updateAddress(address);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

the view that receives Id:

```
@model Clients.Models.AddressModel

@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
{
  @Html.ValidationSummary()

  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)<br />
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Address_Id)<br />
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AddressLine_1) 
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AddressLine_1)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AddressLine_1)<br />
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AddressLine_2) 
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AddressLine_2)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AddressLine_2)<br />
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Postcode) 
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Postcode)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Postcode)<br />
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Town) 
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Town)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Town)<br />
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DateMovedIn) 
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateMovedIn)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DateMovedIn)<br />

  <input type="submit" value="OK"/>
}
```

Comment: Not clear what your asking. Show your view.

Comment: Explain what you exactly needed in the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your razor view is strongly typed to `AddressModel` class. So in your GET action method, create an object of `AddressModel` class, set the `Id` property value to whatever value came to your action method as parameter and send this object to the view.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddAddress (int Id)
{      
    var model = new AddressModel();
    model.Id = id;
    return View(model);
}
```

You need to explicitly pass data to your view from your action method. There is no other magic way to do that. If you do not do that, It will still have the default value of integer type properties, which is 0.

Comment: As explained by Stephen Muecke:  "your GET method has a parameter named Id so its value is added to the route values (look at the action attribute of your element). When your model also has a parameter name Id, the value is bound to your model when you submit the form because the DefaultModelBinder reads the values from route parameters (and query string values) in addition to form values"