# how to send value of Id to the view

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I want to send the value of Id - from Upsert(Id) to the rendered View and I'm struggling. In my previous question there is similar method that is working and this one is not. I think I've done something wrong in Model but I have no Idea what.
Where do I make mistake? This is my controller method:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Upsert(int Id)
    {            
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upsert(UpsertViewModel upsertModel)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("Upsert", upsertModel);
        }

        if (!upsertModel.Address.Address_Id.HasValue   ||upsertModel.Address.Address_Id == 0)
        {
            _addressService.insertAddress(upsertModel.Address);
        }
        else
        {
            _addressService.updateAddress(upsertModel.Address);

        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

And this is my Model:

```
namespace Clients.Models
{
public class UpsertViewModel
{
    public UpsertViewModel(AddressModel address)
    {

        Address = new AddressModel();
        Address.Id = address.Id;
        Address.Address_Id = address.Address_Id;
        Address.AddressLine_1 = address.AddressLine_1;
        Address.AddressLine_2 = address.AddressLine_2;
        Address.Postcode = address.Postcode;
        Address.Town = address.Town;
        Address.DateMovedIn = address.DateMovedIn;

    }
    public AddressModel Address { get; set; }
}
```

}

The view:

```
@model Clients.Models.UpsertViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Address.Id)<br/>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Address.Address_Id)<br />
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Address.AddressLine_1) @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address.AddressLine_1)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Address.AddressLine_1)<br />
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Address.AddressLine_2) @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address.AddressLine_2)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Address.AddressLine_2)<br />
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Address.Postcode) @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address.Postcode)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Address.Postcode)<br />
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Address.Town) @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address.Town)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Address.Town)<br />
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Address.DateMovedIn) @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address.DateMovedIn)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Address.DateMovedIn)<br />


    <input type="submit" value="OK"/>
}
```

Comment: You're opening up your application to "Mass-Assignment Vulnerability"

Comment: You need to return the model to the view in the GET method. (i.e. initialize an instance of your model and set its properties) then `return View(model);` But unless your `UpsertViewModel` class has a parameterless constructor, your code will fail when you submit the form.

Comment: @Stephen yes that works, but if you look at my first question the view get Id without passing model to the view. How?

Comment: What first question?

Comment: Sorry, I had similar question this morning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33968192/how-value-of-id-goes-from-action-method-to-the-view

Comment: Zet, the previous question, what was the value of Id field?

Comment: From your previous question and the code fragment mentioned above, the `Id` field is passed into your "GET" method because the `UpsertViewModel` has an `Id` property in the previous question, but now it's wrapped inside `UpsertViewModel.Address`. The Model Binder is working it's magic via Reflection

Comment: To expand on @Aniket's comment, your GET method has a parameter named `Id` so its value is added to the route values (look at the `action` attribute of your `<form>` element). When your model also has a parameter name `Id`, the value is bound to your model when you submit the form because the `DefaultModelBinder` reads the values from route parameters (and query string values) in addition to form values. In this case your model does not have a property named `Id` (only one named `Address.Id`) so it is not bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the fact that you're opening your application up for Mass Assignment Vulnerability,

Here's something you can try to do: (This is a guess(No VS installed to test), so bear with me)

Add a Default constructor for `UpsertViewModel` and try again.

From your previous question and the code fragment mentioned above, the Id field is passed into your "GET" method because the UpsertViewModel has an Id property in the previous question, but now it's wrapped inside UpsertViewModel.Address. The Model Binder is working its magic via Reflection

By @StephenMuecke

To expand on @Aniket's comment, your GET method has a parameter named Id so its value is added to the route values (look at the action attribute of your `<form>` element). When your model also has a parameter name Id, the value is bound to your model when you submit the form because the DefaultModelBinder reads the values from route parameters (and query string values) in addition to form values. In this case your model does not have a property named Id (only one named Address.Id)

Comment: Ok, can you tell me exactly what's happening? Since, it's hard to understand your question

Comment: Aniket, @Stephen - thank you very much for you help, I have not fixed it yet, but your comments explain a lot and I think I know what to do now.